# SSH into AWS lightsail randomly freezes directly after login

Tags: amazon-web-services, ssh

I am trying to ssh into a lightsail instance on AWS. Login works fine but then the connection freezes while the server responds with the welcome message (see screenshot). These freezes seem to occur randomly
at different points of the message. On roughly every 20th try it makes it through the whole message and in these cases the ssh connection works as expected.

My internet connection ssh to other hosts etc is fine.

[Terminal screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y64HR.png)